# How to retrieve and display 3 highest value in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, web

| id | names | voted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 100 |
| 2 | Mike | 25 |
| 3 | Kathy | 200 |
| 4 | William | 186 |
| 5 | Jasmine | 60 |
| 6 | Sui | 57 |
| 7 | Chris | 43 |
| 8 | Stewie | 103 |
| 9 | Steve | 150 |
| 10 | Jennifer | 97 |

I was able to retrieve the highest value in my table and decided to try retrieving and displaying the 3 highest value from my table but I don't know how and can't seem to find a tutorial or similar codes to what I'm trying to do. What should I do?

My code

```
public function votesList(){
  $data=votes::all()->max('voted')->get();
  return view('list',compact('data'));
}
```

The result I want

| id | names | voted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Kathy | 200 |
| 4 | William | 186 |
| 9 | Steve | 150 |

Answer (score 2):

$data=votes::orderby('voted', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();

Comment: tysm this solved my problem